# How to make all the visible Vue components refetch their Apollo query?

Tags: apollo-client, vue-apollo

I am resetting the Apollo's InMemoryCache from time to time and I would like to have all the visible Vue components to react to the change (either automatically or manually) by refetching all their associated queries.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is to send an event to all visible Vue components using the npm package `vue-bus`, and then in each vue component to call:

```
Object.values(this.$apollo.queries).forEach(query => query.refetch())
```

Comment: Nice! This could also be made easier by using a mixin.